# Why does Zonal Statistics as Table return an empty table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a set of polygons with a field of type "SHORT" indicating whether each unit is habitat (1) or not habitat (0). [image]  I also have a raster file in GRID format (32-bit, floating point): [image] I would like to use the Zonal Statistics as Table tool to calculate two values, the mean value of the raster for habitat areas and the mean value of the raster for non-habitat areas. When I attempt to do so, the tool returns an empty table with no output whatsoever.

I can successfully perform Zonal Statistics as Table using the same polygon layer and 'habitat' field with other rasters in my map document. I have not been able to successfully produce output with this raster and any field in my polygon layer. This leads me to believe there is something about this raster file that is causing this issue, but I cannot figure out what it is. I have read that Zonal Statistics should be able to use a 32-bit, floating point raster as input, so I am wondering if the issue is related to the GRID format or another attribute of this raster I am overlooking.

Comment: Do you have a selection on your data? Is your raster in the same coordinate system?

Comment: @Fezter selection is clear. Both raster and polygon have the same spatial reference: NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving my map document and reopening ArcMap was all it took to fix this issue with the Zonal Statistics as Table tool. Since my raster files were generating using an Add-In (ArcFuels), I am guessing this problem was the result of some quirk with how the Add-In added these GRID files as layers to the map document.